# Role specific commands from ID's fetched from a database

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

So basically, I have gotten so far as to choose which commands should be used by whichever role, I have created some code, but my issue is that for whatever reason, if a user has any of the requirements for any of the commands, they are able to use all of the commands. I have been having issues with this for over a week. It needs to be based on the Role ID's, as the users have to set the allowed role in the database using the role's ID.

This is for my Discord Bot, the database is Firebase, and I am running Discord.JS/Node.JS on VSC. I have tried formatting it so that the role filter comes first, but that got very messy. I don't believe the issue is referencing the role from the database, as I have logged the ID requested in the console, and it returns the correct string. Also, when a user has none of the allowed roles, they are not able to use the commands.

```js
let msg_array = msg.content.split(" ");
    let command = msg_array[0];
    let args = msg_array.slice(1);
    let prefix = "t!"
    let inputtedCMD = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ")
    let cmd = bot.commands.get(inputtedCMD[0])

    let allowedR = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('roles').doc(msg.guild.id).get('role_id').then((r) => {
        if (!r.exists){
            msg.channel.send("You havn't chosen an allowed admin role.")
        } else {
            allowedR = `${r.data().role_id}`;
        }
    })

    let genRole = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('generalRoles').doc(msg.guild.id).get('generalRole_id').then((h) => {
        if (!h.exists){
            msg.channel.send("You havn't chosen an allowed general role.")
        } else {
            genRole = `${h.data().generalRole_id}`;
        }
    })

    let guildOwner = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('guilds').doc(msg.guild.id).get('generalRole_id').then((q) => {
        if (!q.exists){
            msg.channel.send("Cannot access guild owner data.")
        } else {
            guildOwner = `${q.data().guildOwnerID}`;
        }
    })

    let generalRole = msg.guild.roles.get(genRole)
    let adminRole = msg.guild.roles.get(allowedR)


    if (!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    if (inputtedCMD === "databaseReset") {
        if (guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            })
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }
    }

    if (inputtedCMD === "set") {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(adminRole.id) || guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            });
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }
    } 

    if (inputtedCMD === "config","help","invite","patchNotes","ticket") {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(adminRole.id) || msg.member.roles.has(generalRole.id) || guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            }) 
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }  
    }
```

I expect that only the server owner and bot creator to be able to use databaseReset (bot creator ID is the ID included [which is me btw])

Only the admin role of the server and the server owner and the bot creator should be allowed to use the "set" command.

And everyone with the general bot use role should be allowed to use "config", "help", "invite", "patchNotes", and "ticket."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 let prefix = "t!"
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let inputtedCMD = args.shift();
    let cmd = bot.commands.get(inputtedCMD);

    let allowedR = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('roles').doc(msg.guild.id).get('role_id').then((r) => {
        if (!r.exists){
            msg.channel.send("You havn't chosen an allowed admin role.")
        } else {
            allowedR = `${r.data().role_id}`;
        }
    })

    let genRole = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('generalRoles').doc(msg.guild.id).get('generalRole_id').then((h) => {
        if (!h.exists){
            msg.channel.send("You havn't chosen an allowed general role.")
        } else {
            genRole = `${h.data().generalRole_id}`;
        }
    })

    let guildOwner = null

    await firebaseDB.collection('guilds').doc(msg.guild.id).get('generalRole_id').then((q) => {
        if (!q.exists){
            msg.channel.send("Cannot access guild owner data.")
        } else {
            guildOwner = `${q.data().guildOwnerID}`;
        }
    })

    let generalRole = msg.guild.roles.get(genRole)
    let adminRole = msg.guild.roles.get(allowedR)

    if(['databaseReset'].includes(inputtedCMD)) {
        if (guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            })
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }
    }

    if(['set'].includes(inputtedCMD)) {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(adminRole.id) || guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            });
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }
    } 

    if(['config', 'help', 'invite', 'patchNotes', 'ticket'].includes(inputtedCMD)) {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(adminRole.id) || msg.member.roles.has(generalRole.id) || guildOwner === msg.author.id || msg.author.id === "198590136684904448") {
            cmd.run(bot, msg, args, firebaseDB).then(() => {
                console.log("[COMMAND] User w/ permission ran '" + inputtedCMD + "'")
                return;
            }) 
        } else {
            const notAllowed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Hey, " + msg.author.tag, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
                .setDescription("**__No access__** \n *You need the required role to be able to use that command.*")
                .setColor("#00A6ff")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter("Ticket Bot | TBE")
            msg.channel.send(notAllowed)
            return;
        }  
    }
```

So basically, this is the code that worked for me. What I needed to do was implement what @PLASMA chicken posted, and then rearrange the anti-command rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:

```
inputtedCMD === "config","help","invite","patchNotes","ticket"
```

As strings are always true it will give:

```
false, true, true, true, true
```

Wich equals to `true` so its always `true`

So use

```
 if(['config', 'help', 'invite', 'patchNotes', 'ticket'].includes(inputtedCMD)) {
```

instead

Another thing to replace is:

```
let msg_array = msg.content.split(" ");
let command = msg_array[0];
let args = msg_array.slice(1);
let prefix = "t!"
let inputtedCMD = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ")
let cmd = bot.commands.get(inputtedCMD[0])
```

With:

```
let args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
let prefix = "t!"
let inputtedCMD = args.shift();
let cmd = bot.commands.get(inputtedCMD);
```

Before doingthat you would have needed:

```
if (inputtedCMD[0] === "databaseReset") {
```

So the checks would always go to the else
The thing I wrote fixed that

Comment: Doing that makes none of the commands run, regardless of user role. Even 'databaseReset' and 'set' will not run.

Comment: Implementing your changes, and fixing the errors that occur (because of prefix being defined after it being used and simple stuff like that,) yields no improvement. The commands do not run still and there are no errors indicating why.